# c++11 random engines and distributions interaction and cost

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I have a bunch of questions about random engines and distributions, their cost and interaction:

1. Is `std::random_device` an expensive (heavy constructible) object? Should I only create one for my application if possible?
2. Are `RandomNumberDistribution` objects expensive objects or is it mostly dependent of concrete distribution? It seems to me that for example `uniform_int_distribution` should be very light object containing distribution range `[min, max]` and may be (?) some internal state.
3. How does the interaction between `random_device`, `random_engine` and `distribution` work in code below:

   ```
   std::random_device rd;
   std::mt19937 gen(rd());
   std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(1, 10);

   auto random_value = distr(gen);
   ```

What happens in last line? Distribution get next value from random engine and then brings it to desired range `[0, 10]`? Always obviously internal states of some objects should be modified after call: definitely `random_device`, `random_engine` but does `uniform_int_distribution` also have some internal state?

Comment: One question per question, please. Not four.

Comment: Some light reading on [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). Excellent reference, with great examples

Comment: but these questions are related

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Usually it isn't, initialization either is trivial or comaprable to some PRNG initialization, however invoking `operator()` might access OS for secure random number and it could be costly.

2) Mostly depends on *distribution*. They containg distribution parameters (which you can retrieve if you want) and *optionally* some inner state (IIRC most implementation doesn't bother with it). So initializating *distribution* is like initializating small structure.

3) *Distribution* object invokes *generators* `operator()` unspecified amount of times (from 0 to ∞ times) and creates a random number from bit sequence produced by *generator*. Then it returns generated bumber.
It potentially advances *generator* state and might store unused bits produced by *generator* in *distribution* internal state.

`random_device`, probably, does not even has internal state, if it implemented as handle to system RNG. Otherwise, its state is advanced on second line, when you invoke its `operator()` to produce random number you will use as seed for your *generator*.