# Is creating a uniform_int_distribution<int> object expensive?

Tags: c++, random, uniform-distribution

I am writing code where random numbers are being sampled from a uniform distribution who's bounds vary for certain iterations within a for loop, e.g.,

```
std::mt19937 generator{0};
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
  if(conditions are met)
  {
    // low and hi bounds change for each iteration
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> U(low, hi);
    auto sample = U(generator);
  }

}
```

This is the way I currently have the code written, but it's creating and deleting a temporary `std::uniform_int_distribution<int>` object for each iteration where the conditions are met. Is this an expensive process? Could compiler optimizations construct the object outside of the for loop, and instead reconstructs the bounds of the uniform distribution within the if statement? I'm not sure if that's necessarily faster.

Are there other approaches that might be better?

Comment: It shouldn't be.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38845975/c11-random-engines-and-distributions-interaction-and-cost

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but “creating and deleting” should be either “creating and destroying” or “newing and deleting”. In this case, the first inel

Answer (score 4):

`std::uniform_int_distribution` is usually **not expensive** to create and contains only the min/max pair of values as its members. At least that is the case with [stdlibc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/99dee82307f1e163e150c9c810452979994047ce/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/uniform_int_dist.h#L116), [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/78d6a7767ed57b50122a161b91f59f19c9bd0d19/include/algorithm#L2957) and [VC++](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/2ce62b58489bcf93f81a39d883597e666bc34bfe/stl/inc/random#L1744). A good optimizing compiler should be able to eliminate any trace of it entirely.

However, that's not guaranteed, furthermore, a distribution is allowed to be stateful. Though that's more often the case with `normal_distribution`, not `uniform_int_distribution`.

---

Technically it's possible to re-use a distribution and re-initialize it's parameters in a loop:

```
std::mt19937 generator{ 0 };
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> U;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    // low and hi bounds change for each iteration
    U.param(std::uniform_int_distribution<int>::param_type(low, hi));
    auto sample = U(generator);
}
```

The generated code will probably be identical (or slightly worse - check to be sure), and it doesn't solve the issue with `normal_distribution` as changing the params resets the state.